# The directive *ngFor not rendering in simple project

Tags: angular

Please help me get ngFor to render the {{par.name}}

http://plnkr.co/edit/8ChRF4Gb6YtLmmeTRiZY?p=preview

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let par of COMMPAR">
{{par.name}}
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I edited the code on plunkr to now read: <li *ngFor="let par of COMMPAR"> but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The scope for templates is the component instance. Any static or global references are not supported from within the template.

I just added

```
commpar = COMMPAR;
```

to your component. [**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/IaU3Pqke580ZY1wDcVPx?p=preview)